# Workbench doesn't allow delete table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table `newsletter` and I want to delete/update/insert data in it, but when I type

```
delete * from crm_base.newsletter
```

for example, it gets an red "X" in the line and gives me the following error message:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from crm_base.newsletter_temp' at line 1.
```

I already unchecked the safe update mode in preferences and resetted workbench, but it still gives me the same error.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from crm_base.newsletter
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not correct, use `DELETE FROM crm_base.newsletter WHERE condition`. Check the [Delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/delete.html) syntax reference.